Memory Error with Cosine Similarity on Large Matrix (47605 x 73875) in Jupyter Notebook
I'm working on a recommendation system using python in Jupyter Notebook and need to compute cosine similarity for a large count matrix using sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity. However, I'm encountering a memory error due to the matrix size.

Matrix Shape: (47605, 73875) Error: Unable to allocate 25.7 GiB for an
array with shape (46628, 73881) and data type int64 System Specs: 8GB
RAM, 512 SSD

I'm looking for advice on alternative methods to efficiently compute cosine similarity for such a large matrix on my setup. Ideally, a solution that can handle the computation without running into memory errors.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any suggestions?

I doubt Jupyter has anything to do with this. you're running out of RAM. Try lazily loading and then computing on batches of matrix. You can try polars for this.

Im not sure what you have tried but I can provide some code I used a few years ago. I used this to compare descriptions of shows to find similar ones.
This part I cleaned up the text and with a custom function filter_words. All filter_words does is get rid of stop words whatnot.
cleaned_description_list = []
for des in anime_description:
    cleaned_description_list.append(filter_words(des))


#vectorize and tokenize
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(cleaned_description_list)

Then after I get the users phrase and run the cosign similarity.
#Get filtered user description
user_description = filter_words(user_description)

#This vectorizes the users entry
Y = vectorizer.transform([user_description])

#Get similarity
similarities = [cosine_similarity(Y[0],X[i])[0][0] for i in range(len(cleaned_description_list))]
thresh = max(similarities) * 0.25

If anything try and break your data up into chucks if at all possible.
